# how to place div on 4 box div in bootstrap version 3 css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to create one div which will reside on few box like this :

[image]

what i would like to achieve is when i click on small button, i want to show /hide that div

my fiddle is here :

http://jsfiddle.net/u6hy87vr/ ( this is responsive design so may be it doest look like as picture, please make jsfiddle wider)

i used following defaut modelpop to show, but i think it will not help me in this case.please help me

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: How would you like it to behave when the page is narrow (the way it is on jsfiddle right now) ? On your picture, the DIV you want to popout begins in the box 5 and ends on 11 (or begins on 7 and ends on 12, respectively). But when it's narrow - which boxes should it cover?

Comment: i want to show popup as 2 column - 1 for left and 1 for right, and if my connect goes to very small device it will cover only 1 column